# What to do if there are no functions left?

Tags: lua, luajit

What can I do if there are no functions left?

Is there a function that can't be redefined or at least is there a way to bring functions back to their original state?

For example:

```
for k, v in pairs(_G) do _G[k] = nil end
print("testing") -- error: attempt to index global '_G' (a nil value)
```

I know it doesn't make any sense to delete all functions and then try calling them, but just imagine that you don't have any functions and libraries at all. What would you do then?

Comment: You have an ideal sandbox now :)  Jokes aside, just copy the functions you need later into local variables before wiping the global environment.

Comment: Write your own libraries from scratch?

Comment: `return 42 -- or whatever the answer is` The return list is the only effect the function can have.

Answer (score 1):

Use local variables to store the functions you still need, then set everything in the environment table to `nil`. For instance, it is a good idea to remove things like the `debug` library and maybe some IO functions; things like `print`, though, are probably good to keep around.

Comment: thanks for answering, but unfortunately it won't help because a hacker can copy any function before a script loaded